# Is there a function in R to split vector by percentage groups?

Tags: r, split

For example I have a column:

```
x <- c(-0.5, 1.1, 6.0, 4.5, 0.1, -0.2)
```

I want to add a new column where each value is assigned with a 3 percentage group
For example :

- if x -3<=x<0 => group -3
- if x 3<=x<6 => group 6

So I will have a new column: 
c(-3, 3, 9, 6, 3, -3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
# Define the value using the ranges:


num_frame$perc_group <- ifelse(num_frame$num_vec < 0 & num_frame$num_vec >= -3, -3,

                               ifelse(num_frame$num_vec == 0, 0,

                                      ifelse(num_frame$num_vec > 0 & num_frame$num_vec <= 3, 3, 6)))
```

Data:

```
num_frame <- structure(list(num_vec = c(-0.5, 1.1, 6, 4.5, 0.1, -0.2)),

                       class = "data.frame",

                       row.names = c(NA,  -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findInterval` or `cut` for this

```
x <- c(-0.5, 1.1, 6.0, 4.5, 0.1, -0.2)
brks <- seq(-3, 9, 3)
lbls <- c(-3,3,6,9)

lbls[findInterval(x, brks)]
#[1] -3  3  9  6  3 -3
```

Or as mentioned by @StupidWolf using `cut`

```
cut(x, breaks=brks,right=FALSE, labels=lbls)
```

Comment: The 2nd label is 3 instead of 0, so I guess you need to use this: cut(x,breaks=br,right=FALSE,labels=c(-3,3,6,9))?

Comment: @StupidWolf Yes, you are right. I have updated the answer. Thanks :)